# How to change tick size of noUislider

Tags: nouislider

I wonder if it's possible to change the tick size of noUiSlider? I would like to reduce the height/length of the ticks but I can't find CSS selector of it. Thank you[image: The picture attached is my slider where the tick size can look smaller.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the CSS selector for the property of tick size. The CSS code below works for my horizontal noUislider.

```
    .noUi-marker-horizontal.noUi-marker-large {
        height: 10px;
    }
```